# upgrading system and lts-trusty packages

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, lts

I use UBuntu 14.04 LTS and I regular perform a system update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I found a group of packages which names look like this "**package-lts-trusty**" , for example:

```
libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty
```

Those packges are not installed in my system. Why dist-uprade doesn't install them ? I assume that those "lts-trusty" packages contains the most actual content. How to install them all automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

These packages should not install. They are transitional for upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. And 'trusty' is the name of 14.04 release.